# error in compile c++ code right operand of comma operator has no effect

Tags: c++, compilation, codeblocks, cin, comma-operator

my c++ Code:

```
std::cin >> newptr->boarding_time.hour,newptr->boarding_time.mins;
```

error:

> C:\Users\hkteco-ir\Desktop\c++\dsdsa\main.cpp|223|warning: right operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]|

Comment: What do you not understand about the error? If you want to `cin` two variables at once, separate them with `>>`, not a comma, e.g. `std::cin >> newptr->boarding_time.hour >> newptr->boarding_time.mins;` (if this is what you're trying to accomplish, I'm kind of guessing here).

Comment: That's not an error, it's just warning™

Comment: thanks for your response

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using [comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator), and according to the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), the code is equivalent as

```
std::cin >> newptr->boarding_time.hour;
newptr->boarding_time.mins;
```

and the 2nd statement doesn't have any actual effect at all.

You might want

```
std::cin >> newptr->boarding_time.hour >> newptr->boarding_time.mins;
```